# python webscraping and write data into csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to save all the data(i.e all pages) in single csv file but this code only save the final page data.Eg Here  url[] contains 2 urls. the final csv only contains the 2nd url data.
I'm clearly doing something wrong in the loop.but i dont know what.
And also this page contains 100 data points. But this code only write first 44 rows.
please help this issue.............

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
url = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/npo","http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/npo?s=100"]
for ur in url:
    r = requests.get(ur)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    g_data = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "hdrlnk"})
    gen_list=[]
    for row in g_data:
       try:
            name = row.text
       except:
            name=''
       try:
            link = "http://sfbay.craigslist.org"+row.get("href")
       except:
            link=''
       gen=[name,link]
       gen_list.append(gen)

with open ('filename2.csv','wb') as file:
    writer=csv.writer(file)
    for row in gen_list:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the gen_list is being initialized again inside your loop that runs over the urls.

```
gen_list=[]
```

Move this line outside the for loop.

```
...
url = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/npo","http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/npo?s=100"]
gen_list=[]
for ur in url:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

i found your post later, wanna try this method:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

final_data = []
url = "https://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sss"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
get_details = soup.find_all(class_="result-row")

for details in get_details:
    getclass = details.find_all(class_="hdrlnk")
    for link in getclass:
        link1 = link.get("href")
        sublist = []
        sublist.append(link1)
        final_data.append(sublist)
print(final_data)

filename = "sfbay.csv"
with open("./"+filename, "w") as csvfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
    csvfile.writerow("")
    for i in range(0, len(final_data)):
        csvfile.writerow(final_data[i])
```